# How to get 2 models in 1 template?

Tags: python

I could get 2 model in class:
Views.py:

```html
class StoreSearchList(SearchListView):
    model = Shop, Menu
    template_name = "homepage/searchresult.html"
    filter_class = StoreFilter
```

searchresult.html:

```html
{% for shop in object_list.Shop %}
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                        <article class="popular-listing-post">
                            <div class="post-thumb">
                                <img src="{% static 'homepage/images/post/9.jpg' %}" alt="img" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="listing-info">
                                    <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></h4>
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{shop.name}}</p>
                                </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send multiple data to template page then you can use below line of code.

```
def your_fun_name() :
    return render_template('searchresult.html:', shop_data = shop, menu_data= menu);
```

Comment: But the filter_class line to filter when searching can't be in render

Comment: I am not able to understand you exact requirement. Can you please describe it more.

Comment: I want to create an html containing the Menu model, and when used, only needs {% include 'menu.html'%}, no need to pass the menu variable = Menu.object.all (). It is similar to ViewComponent in ASP.NET Core